# wxPython widgets are one on top of the other

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm bulding a wxpython GUI.

When I'm running the code all the components are in the left-top corner, on top of each other.
When I resize the window, they align as planned.

[The window before resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsueA.png)

[The window after resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gkjx.png)

How can I fix this?

my code:

```
class Screen(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, title):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(900,500))

    self.SetBackgroundColour("#E4F1FE")
    self.Show(True)

    self.InitUI()

def InitUI(self):

    pnlMain = wx.Panel(self, size=(900,500))

    # Setup Font
    font = wx.SystemSettings_GetFont(wx.SYS_SYSTEM_FONT)
    font.SetPointSize(9)

    # Setup horizontal box sizer
    self.bsMain = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.bsMain.SetDimension(0,0,900,500)

    # Setup LEFT box sizer
    self.bsLeft = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.bsLeft.SetMinSize((3*(self.GetSize()[0]/4),self.GetSize()[1]))

    # Make add button
    btnAdd = wx.Button(pnlMain, label="+", size=(50,50))

    # Add all the components to the LEFT sizer
    self.bsLeft.Add(btnAdd, flag = wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM | wx.ALIGN_LEFT )

    # Setup RIGHT bsMain sizer
    self.bsRight = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.bsRight.SetMinSize((self.GetSize()[0]/4,self.GetSize()[1]))

    # Make users headline
    stUsers = wx.StaticText(pnlMain, label="USERS")
    stUsers.SetFont(font)

    # Make users list control
    lcUsers = wx.ListCtrl(pnlMain,style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
    lcUsers.Show(True)
    lcUsers.InsertColumn(0,"user")
    lcUsers.InsertColumn(1,"status")

    # Add all the components to the RIGHT sizer
    self.bsRight.Add((-1,10))
    self.bsRight.Add(stUsers, flag=wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, border=5)
    self.bsRight.Add((-1,10))
    self.bsRight.Add(lcUsers, flag=wx.EXPAND)


    # Add the vertical sizers to the horizontal sizer
    self.bsMain.Add(self.bsLeft)
    self.bsMain.Add(self.bsRight)

    # Add the vertical sizer to the panel
    pnlMain.SetSizer(self.bsMain)
```

Comment: you need to call `Layout` on the sizer, or `Refresh` on the window, to force the sizer to actually calculate sizes/offsets for the child windows. This happens automatically when you resize, which is why it works then.

Comment: Thanks! it helped alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem for new wxPython programmers. The solution is almost always a call to the top level sizer's `Layout` method. Occasionally you'll need to call the top-level parent's `Layout` instead. In your case, either will work. You can add:

```
pnlMain.Layout()
```

or

```
self.bsMain.Layout()
```

to the bottom of `InitUI` method and it should force your widgets to redraw in their correct locations. I've seen some widgets behave badly because they start out with a zero size until their shown. In those cases, I have usually needed to use `wx.CallAfter` to call `Layout`. Anyway, here's a complete example using your code:

```
import wx

class Screen(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(900,500))

        self.SetBackgroundColour("#E4F1FE")
        self.Show(True)

        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):

        pnlMain = wx.Panel(self, size=(900,500))

        # Setup Font
        font = wx.SystemSettings_GetFont(wx.SYS_SYSTEM_FONT)
        font.SetPointSize(9)

        # Setup horizontal box sizer
        self.bsMain = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.bsMain.SetDimension(0,0,900,500)

        # Setup LEFT box sizer
        self.bsLeft = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.bsLeft.SetMinSize((3*(self.GetSize()[0]/4),self.GetSize()[1]))

        # Make add button
        btnAdd = wx.Button(pnlMain, label="+", size=(50,50))

        # Add all the components to the LEFT sizer
        self.bsLeft.Add(btnAdd, flag = wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM | wx.ALIGN_LEFT )

        # Setup RIGHT bsMain sizer
        self.bsRight = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.bsRight.SetMinSize((self.GetSize()[0]/4,self.GetSize()[1]))

        # Make users headline
        stUsers = wx.StaticText(pnlMain, label="USERS")
        stUsers.SetFont(font)

        # Make users list control
        lcUsers = wx.ListCtrl(pnlMain,style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        lcUsers.Show(True)
        lcUsers.InsertColumn(0,"user")
        lcUsers.InsertColumn(1,"status")

        # Add all the components to the RIGHT sizer
        self.bsRight.Add((-1,10))
        self.bsRight.Add(stUsers, flag=wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, border=5)
        self.bsRight.Add((-1,10))
        self.bsRight.Add(lcUsers, flag=wx.EXPAND)


        # Add the vertical sizers to the horizontal sizer
        self.bsMain.Add(self.bsLeft)
        self.bsMain.Add(self.bsRight)

        # Add the vertical sizer to the panel
        pnlMain.SetSizer(self.bsMain)
        self.bsMain.Layout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = Screen(None, 'Layout')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Note: I've rarely needed to call `Refresh`. I think `Layout` does so automatically.